# How to figure out if an Uber ride is actually an UberEats delivery

Tags: uber-api

I am trying to figure out if an Uber ride is actually an UberEats delivery.

I thought the way to do that is with the products API, but when I tried to use the product API resource, all I got back is "Unauthorized access to product".

I can usually use the product API resource for other product ids. But this I cannot.

Comment: Hey Yarden,

Can you provide a little more clarification about what you're attempting to do? Generally speaking the external API does not support UberEats

Comment: I am trying filter out uberEats from the user history I get.

I got a ride ID `a40c6114-f4ab-46a7-b54e-9731bc4447bc`. I think it's an UberEATS. I would like to know if it is.

Comment: We did some investigation and it looks like you've identified an issue with our API. Thanks for reporting it! We're looking into how we want to approach this issue, and I'll update this thread with an answer once we've rolled out a fix :)

Comment: @RichardArtoul your my hero! waiting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug which is now resolved. UberEATS should not be surfaced in the products endpoint.