# Does Uber Eats have an API and if so where can I found out more information

Tags: uber-api

Does Uber Eats have an API and if so where can I found out more information.

I know I can integrate with Uber just wondering on the logistics with uber eats and would like to be able to integrate with current platform.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291022/how-to-figure-out-if-an-uber-ride-is-actually-a-ubereats-delivery) post might be helpful. It looks like "the external API does not support UberEATS" as of March 30th and that there is no way to tell if a certain Uber ride ID is UberEATS or not. Seems it might be in the works, though.